# Markdown output not fitting column

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, ieee

I'm writing an article in RStudio (global setting is using knitr) trying to make the output generated by a chunk of code fit the specification of the IEEE jornal, butthe output will wonder off the column (text is organized in two columns).

I've tried specifying the out.width of the code chunk with the column width (out.width="\columnwidth") but it doesn't seem to do much. I've also tried specifying the same parameter with "\linewidth" and "\textwidth" but still I get the same output to the pdf. I've also tried scaling down the size by puting in "%10" and "1%" but no sucess.

<>=
levels(classObito$estado_fisico)
@

Expected the output of the code chunk to fit into the column, but it wonders off the page or to the other column.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with adding option(width="50") inside the code chunk